# JQuery using single function instead of multiple

Tags: jquery, centering, simplify

Hello I would like to simplify those 4 similar functions. Only selectors are changing finally. How could I proceed please ? Many thanx !

```
$('.box.standard .title').css({
                'position' : 'absolute',
                'left' : '50%',
                'top' : '50%',
                'margin-left' : -$('.box.standard .title').outerWidth()/2,
                'margin-top' : -$('.box.standard .title').outerHeight()/2
            });

            $('.box.large .title').css({
                'position' : 'absolute',
                'left' : '50%',
                'top' : '50%',
                'margin-left' : -$('.box.large .title').outerWidth()/2,
                'margin-top' : -$('.box.large .title').outerHeight()/2
            });

            $('.box.wide .title').css({
                'position' : 'absolute',
                'left' : '50%',
                'top' : '50%',
                'margin-left' : -$('.box.wide .title').outerWidth()/2,
                'margin-top' : -$('.box.wide .title').outerHeight()/2
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var myArray = ['.box.standard', '.box.large', '.box.wide'];

for (var i of myArray) {

  $(i+' .title').css({
                'position' : 'absolute',
                'left' : '50%',
                'top' : '50%',
                'margin-left' : -$(i+' .title').outerWidth()/2,
                'margin-top' : -$(i+' .title').outerHeight()/2
            });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it a function and use it whenever you like:

```
function myFunction(cssClasses){  

  $(cssClasses).css({
                    'position' : 'absolute',
                    'left' : '50%',
                    'top' : '50%',
                    'margin-left' : -$('.box.wide .title').outerWidth()/2,
                    'margin-top' : -$('.box.wide .title').outerHeight()/2
                });

}

myFunction('.box.standard .title');
myFunction('.box.large .title');
myFunction('.box.wide .title');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to help you access `this`, which refers to the selected element. This should do it:

```
       $('.box.standard .title, .box.large .title, .box.wide .title').css({
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'left' : '50%',
            'top' : '50%',
            'margin-left' : function() {
                return -$(this).outerWidth()/2;
            },
            'margin-top' : function() {
                return -$(this).outerHeight()/2;
            }
        });
```